# convert image-segmentation class output to image in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-segmentation

I have image segmentation problem ,I have list of my classes in a `(num_class,3)` array which contains color of each class. after a u-net I'll have a Probability tensor by `(width,height,num_class)` shape which I want to convert to image  `(width,height,3)`. how can I do this?

```
class_colors=[[128,0,0],[0,128,0],...] #(num_class,3)
logit=unet(img) # (W,H,num_class)
probs=tf.nn.softmax(logit)
predictions=tf.argmax(probs)
prediction_image= ? # (W,H,3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `tf.gather_nd` but first you need to declare the `class_colors` as a tensorflow variable. Check the following example (image size 50x50, 2 classes):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

predictions = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(tf.random_normal([50,50,2])),axis=-1) #(50,50)
class_colors = tf.Variable([[255,0,0],[0,255,0]]) #(2,3)
prediction_image = tf.gather_nd(class_colors, tf.expand_dims(predictions,axis=-1)) #(50,50,3)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(prediction_image).shape) #(50, 50, 3)
```

Alternatively, you can evaluate the `predictions` tensor and use numpy operations.